# Web browser automatization using Lua

Tags: lua, automation

Could anyone suggest any framework or library for web browser automatization in Lua?

My friend only programs in Lua, and he wants to do some automatization. For example, go on to a website and submit a form.

Comment: Just learn JavaScript; it's very similar and already runs in the browser.

Comment: It's not what he wants.

Comment: Then he might simply not get what he wants. I'm not aware of any such tool, but maybe someone else knows of one.

Comment: Only thing I could think of is Luasocket, which allows you to send and receive (GET, POST) HTTP requests. You could search the response from the GET and modify your POST request accordingly, but it would be difficult and tedious, from personal experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar requirement. I wrote a webdriver module that you can use with Lua. I have it [Luawebdriver Github](https://github.com/aryajur/luawebdriver). You can automate any browser that supports the webdriver API. I have tried it with Microsoft Edge and it works very well. You need to have the webdriver server for edge running which is available [enter link description here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/)